# Swift - why can't I append one Double array with another Double array

Tags: arrays, swift, append, double

I want to append this array

```
var rates  = [1.00, 0.98, 0.97, 0.90, 0.86, 0.84, 0.80, 0.79, 0.78, 0.77, 0.76, 0.76, 0.68, 0.66, 0.63, 0.61, 0.60, 0.60, 0.59, 0.57, 0.57, 0.55, 0.53, 0.53, 0.51, 0.51, 0.49, 0.48, 0.47, 0.46, 0.46, 0.46, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.43, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42, 0.42]
```

with this one

```
var ratesone  = [2.00, 1.98, 1.97, 0.99, 0.89]
```

under certain conditions 
This code does not work 
rates.append(ratesone)
This is error message - I have Googled this for days without satisfactory answer

> 'Cannot convert value of type '[Double]' to expected argument type
>   'Double''

These are both Double arrays so why on earth is it trying to convert

Answer (score 1):

Just join arrays using `rates += ratesone`

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to append the entire array as a single entity (`[2.00, 1.98, 1.97, 0.99, 0.89]`, of type `[Double]`), into an array whose members are `Double` (not `[Double])`.

You're looking for `Array.append(contentsOf:)`, or more popularly, the `+=` operator.